# To write a linq query to get selected name count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

Here I need to get the total count of name Murugan my output should be "2" . How to write Linq Query for that

**Linq:**

```
Person[] names = {new Person { Name = "Murugan", Money = 15000 },
                                 new Person{Name="Vel",Money=17000},
                                 new Person{Name="Murugan",Money=1000},
                                  new Person{Name="Subramani",Money=18000},
                                 new Person{Name="Vel",Money=2500}};
var result = from val in names
         where val.Name == "Murugan" 
         select val;
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
var count = names.Count(x=>x.Name=="Murugan");
```

Comment: `.ToList()` is not needed.

Comment: This meets the stated requirements, but a group by would probably provide a more useful result.

Comment: I removed my answer. I thought he wanted the sum of money for the given person, my bad... Your answer is the right and shortest one. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this,

```
var result = (from val in names
                          where val.Name == "Murugan"
                          select val).Count();
```

Comment: Version with `Count(x=>x.Name=="Murugan")` is shorter version of that :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use this:

```
  var result = from val in names
               where val.Name == "Murugan"
               group val by val.Name into g
               select new { Count = g.Count()                   
               };
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit overkill for a count? :)

Comment: It might be, but it provide more possibilities to add other information, like the Sum, average,... of money. after all it depends on the context

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
Person[] names = { new Person { Name = "Murugan", Money = 15000 },
                   new Person{Name="Vel",Money=17000},
                   new Person{Name="Murugan",Money=1000},
                   new Person{Name="Subramani",Money=18000},
                   new Person{Name="Vel",Money=2500} };

var result = (from val in names
              where val.Name == "Murugan"
              select val).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: -1: He wants the number of occurences of the given name in the list. You're just converting an IEnumerable<Person> to a List<Person>.

Comment: and then using result.Count to get the value, and he specified which name he wants to query for (Here I need to get the total count of name Murugan my output should be "2"). Try the code.

Comment: Didn't see the `result.Count` there, my bad! Although wudziks answer is simpler ;)

Comment: I agree, he did ask for Linq and not Lambda expression though?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from val in names
                         where val.Name == "Murugan"
                         select val).Count ();
```

linq returns IEnumerable which has Count ()

Comment: was typing on the phone so didn't realize there was already an answer